Is it possible to remote debug c++ over ssh with vscode with the source code remaining local only?
I've been struggling to set up debugging for my project, I want to do the following:

Compile source code (c++ project) on my windows PC using vscode and WSL.
Launch the executable on my embedded linux board through ssh with vscode.
debug this exe with gdb over ssh.

This is possible with visual studio, but I have not been able to make it work with vscode. I want to use vscode because I build my project with a yocto SDK and visual studio intellisense can't make sense of it, vscode intellisense works fine however.
I managed to get somewhere relatively close using the 'native debug' extension following the process outlined in this article. However, I far as I've been able to tell, this method requires copying the code over to the remote machine. I don't want to do this as my code base is relatively large.
I also found this question: VS Code: Local source code with remote run/debug, there is an answer that suggests pipe transport but there is very little information online regarding how to implement this.
Does anyone have a similar set up and could provide some ideas what I might try next?

Yes it can be done. I found my answer in this article: Yocto Programming with Visual Studio Code
The key things for me were using the script to launch the gdbserver on the target machine and using gdb-multiarch on the local machine.
With this impletmentation you don't need native debug, you can just use cppdbg and there's no need to copy the source code to the target machine.

Please read How to answer, especially the paragraph about "Provide context for links",to me the context provided is very thin....
